# Sphinx индексация

Tags: php, база-данных, поиск, поисковые-системы, sphinxsearch

есть ли возможность настроить автоиндексацию при добавлении, редактировании и удалении в Sphinx ?

Comment: Поставьте реиндекс на крон

Comment: ну крон работает, насколько я знаю, только по заданному промежутку времени

Comment: Ну и ставите раз в 5 минут и все.

Comment: ну раз в 5 минут придется индексировать всю таблицу, мне кажется это слишком трудоемко, а нельзя отдельно индексировать поля по id?

Comment: Ну один раз в 30 мин. А вообще один селект это довольно быстро

Comment: 30 минут это долго.

Comment: Все я нашел информацию, спасибо за желание помочь мне, если вам интересно можете почитать "RT (real-time) индексы"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44088/discussion-between---and-naumov).